# xsd:dateTime returning null when mapping to java.util.Date

Tags: java-8, timezone, weblogic, xquery, java.util.date

I am trying to make a webservice work that sends a date value like the following:

```
<fecha>2018-09-19-05:00</fecha>
```

With XQuery type:

```
<xsd:element name="fecha" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
```

To a `java.util.Date` object but it sets to `null`.

When parameter is like this:

```
<fecha>2018-09-19T00:00:00-05:00</fecha>
```

Date object is set properly.

I tried changing `Date` type to `java.util.Calendar` but got same result.

The Java application I'm working on was recently upgraded to java 8. There is a java 6 application currently working in production with same date parameter format for this service and same `xsd` type. Maybe something changed with java 8 update?

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I am very new to XQuery, and English is not my native language.

Comment: Which type of service you are using?

Comment: @Abhay Its a wsdl service

Answer (score 1):

The element instance you have shown is a valid instance of `xs:date`, not of `xs:dateTime` (there is no time component). I don't know what your toolchain is doing, but if your data isn't valid against the schema, then fixing that seems a good starting point.